# ActionBar Spinner dark text with Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using a custom `BaseAdapter` with the following getView() method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbarspinner_header, parent, false);
        } else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
            assert convertView != null;
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText("Manage stores");
            textView.setTextColor(0xffffff);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

And even though I force the text color to show white (I have tried without forcing it), it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textView.setTextColor(0xffffff);` sets the text to transparent white.